# Syntax error on token "}", but i really cannot find it

Tags: java, android

I'm learning android now, and i write some simple codes according to the book.

i create an android project named Chapter03_ResourceActivity, then create **test.xml** in res/xml/ folder, contents are as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <customer name = "first_name" age = "1" email = "first_name@xml.com" />
    <customer name = "second_name" age = "2" email = "second_name@xml.com" />
</resources>
```

and type codes in **Chapter03_ResourceActivity.java**(src/com.app.MainActivity/Chapter03_ResourceActivity.java) as follows:

```
package com.app.MainActivity;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Chapter03_ResourceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button myButton;
    private TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_xml);
        final TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_xml);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlResourceParser xrp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.test);
            int counter = 0;
            try {
                while(xrp.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if(xrp.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
                        String name = xrp.getName();
                        if(name.equals("customer")) {
                            counter ++;
                            sb.append(counter + " Customer" + "\n");
                            sb.append(xrp.getAttributeValue(0) + "\n");
                            sb.append(xrp.getAttributeValue(1) + "\n");
                            sb.append(xrp.getAttributeValue(2) + "\n\n");
                        } 
                        xrp.next();
                    }
                } 
            myTextView.setText(sb.toString());    <<--Here Eclipse mark an error. 
                catch(XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
            }
        });           <<--Here Eclipse mark another error.
    }
}
```

Two errors have been marked in the code. i tried to solve it by myself, but forgive my dull, i cannot find it. i counted the number of "{" and  "}" for many times, and just find they are right equal. Maybe i really miscounted? Or something i dont konw made this error? Any help appreciated.

Comment: you def need another one to close your try block and then get rid of one after the catch block

Comment: You should clean up / format / correct the indentation of the file (all in Eclipse's `Source` menu). Then structure problems like this are often visible at once.

Comment: Heres a tip for next time, in Eclipse you can double-click right inside a left paren (`{`, `(`, `[`) and it will highlight up the matching right paren (`}`, `(`, `[`). You can use that next time to find simple syntactical errors like this.

Comment: Thanks. i dont know the functionality before. it's very useful. @his

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
catch(XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

should be:

```
} catch(XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
```

It's not the *quantity* that's causing you grief, just the placement. Your `catch` is actually *inside* the `try` block at the moment rather than immediately after it.

Answer (score 1):

You start your try block with a { but you never close it with a }. So you should add an } before your catch statement.

Answer (score 1):

The line that eclipse mark as an erro is out of any block of code ...

Add a closing curling brace before the catch and move that line in this way :

```
public class Chapter03_ResourceActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button myButton;
    private TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_xml);
        final TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_xml);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            XmlResourceParser xrp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.test);
            int counter = 0;
            try {
                while(xrp.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if(xrp.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
                        String name = xrp.getName();
                        if(name.equals("customer")) {
                            counter ++;
                            sb.append(counter + " Customer" + "\n");
                            sb.append(xrp.getAttributeValue(0) + "\n");
                            sb.append(xrp.getAttributeValue(1) + "\n");
                            sb.append(xrp.getAttributeValue(2) + "\n\n");
                        } 
                        xrp.next();
                    }

                } 
                 myTextView.setText(sb.toString());    <<--Now is fine
                } catch(XmlPullParserException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }   
            }
        });
    }
}
```